# Galois theory: Generalization of Abel's Theorem? 

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory

Let $L$ stand for the field obtained by adjoining to 
${\Bbb Q}$ all roots of all polynomials of the
form $x^n+ax+b$, $a,b\in {\Bbb Q}$.

What polynomials $p$ don't split over $L$?  In particular, how low
can one make the degree of such a $p$?

Classically, $S_n$ occurs as a Galois group for
certain $x^n+ax+b$, $n\geq 5$.  That means that
obstructions for $p$ splitting over such $L$
must reflect information beyond the Galois group
of $p$.  So absent a full answer to my question,
what candidates does one have for such an obstruction?
For example, does the form of the polynomial single
out particular representations of $S_n$?

Again, absent
a full answer, does the literature contain theorems about
polynomials not splitting over similar large extension of ${\Bbb Q}$?

Comment: Utterly trivial remarks (which I make only because they could have been included in the question): any quadratic poly is already of the form $x^2+ax+b$, and "completing the cube" says that any cubic is of the form $x^3+ax+b$ after a linear change of variables, so the smallest degree of such a $p$, if one exists, is at least 4. 

Comment: Welcome, David! 

Comment: A stupid remark on your question: you are asking whether all extensions are contained in an extension of Q generated by a root of $x^n+ax+b$. Say you are more ambitious and ask if equality holds, i.e. if it has a generator of this shape. If so, in particular any extension of Q_p has a generator of this kind and any finite extension as well. If n=6 and p=7, all such polynomials are reducible, so this ambitious generality is not true. But you can ask the original question in finite fields to have a hint of what the answer is...

Comment: I realized in the cold light of morning (but haven't had the time till now to write), that I simply hadn't asked the question I'd intended.

I'd simply edit my original question, but now it seems my accidental question has some interest in itself.  

What I had meant to say was: 

Let $L$ stand for the smallest extension of ${\Bbb Q}$ closed under the operation of adjoining all roots of polynomials of the form $x^n+ax+b, a,b∈L$. 

Should I start a new question?

Comment: Sure, start a new question, and link to it from here.

Comment: Thanks Scott...and done

http://mathoverflow.net/questions/48855/galois-theory-generalization-of-abels-theorem-better-version

Comment: @David: You did not specify whether n is fixed or not.
@Kevin: using Tschirnhausen transformations you can reduce, if I recall it correctly, even quartic and quintic polynomials to this special form. A good place to look for confirmation is King's "Beyond the quartic".